# Ignore bash backtick execution without escaping the ` character in git commit

Tags: git, bash

I use backtick character in my commits very often. I also usually commit using `git commit  -m`

When I run a command like this

```
git commit -m "add `foo`"
```

Bash tries to execute `foo`.

I can use backslash `\` to escape the backtick but I am wishing for a better solution to avoid escaping backtick all the time.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
git commit -m 'add `foo`'
```

Variables, backticks, and `$(...)` are expanded in double quotes, but not single quotes.

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: You should get in the habit of using single quotes all the time, _except_ when you actually need expansion inside the quotes.

Comment: It's cool, but is not helps me. I use single quotes, but the some command prompt ("> ") appears after I type "enter".

Comment: That will happen if you have unbalanced quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Back tick in shell are considered as command and are executed. If the command is not a valid one, it leaves a empty string.

Refer this Great post https://joelclermont.com/post/2021-02/backticks-in-git-commit-messages/.